# Broker Acknowledgement Rabbit MQ in Micronaut 2.2.1 not woking

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I am trying to get the Broker Acknowledgement using RabbitMQ in Micronaut.

**Listener**

```
@RabbitListener
public class ProductListener {

    @Queue(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS)
    public String find(String text) {
        return text.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Get(value = "/{text}", single = true)
    public Maybe<String> Find(String text) {
        iproductProducer.find(text).subscribe(item ->{
            System.out.println(item);
        });
        return null;
    }
```

**Producer**

```
@RabbitClient(ProductTopicConstants.FETE_BIRD_EXCHANGE)
public interface IProductProducer {
    @Binding(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS)
    Maybe<String> find(String text);
}
```

**UPDATE - #1**

```
@RabbitClient(ProductTopicConstants.FETE_BIRD_EXCHANGE)
    public interface IProductProducer {
        @Binding(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCTS)
        Completable find(String text);
    }
```

As per the documentation

Client methods support two return types, void and a reactive type. If the method returns void, the message will be published and the method will return without acknowledgement. If a reactive type is the return type, a "cold" publisher will be returned that can be subscribed to.

But in the controller `System.out.println(item);` the acknowledgment never gets.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't looking for broker acknowledgement. You are describing RPC. The [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-rabbitmq/latest/guide/#rpc) clearly states how to set this up. From what I can tell, it seems you are missing `@RabbitProperty(name = "replyTo", value = "amq.rabbitmq.reply-to")` on the client.

Comment: How do I get the broker acknowledgment?

Comment: If you really only care about acknowledgement then you should return a `Completable`. There are no items emitted for just an acknowledgement so it makes sense your println is not happening